# Is it possible to rearrange the order of indexes of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the structures like this:

```
tbl_riwayat_jabatan | CREATE TABLE `tbl_riwayat_jabatan` (
  `id_riwayat_jabatan` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_pegawai` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_jabatan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jabatan` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipe_jabatan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_keterangan_jabatan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_eselon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_skpd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `skpd` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `tmt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_sk_jabatan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tgl_sk_jabatan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pejabat_penetapan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `no_sk_pelantikan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tgl_sk_pelantikan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pejabat_pelantik` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sumpah_jabatan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img_sk_jabatan` longblob NOT NULL,
  `img_sk_pelantikan` longblob NOT NULL,
  `urut` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kedudukan` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `jenis_jabfung` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `jenjang_jabfung` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `status_supervisi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catatan_dari_bkd` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_riwayat_jabatan`),
  KEY `id_pegawai` (`id_pegawai`),
  KEY `id_skpd` (`id_skpd`),
  KEY `id_jabatan` (`id_jabatan`),
  KEY `tmt` (`tmt`),
  KEY `id_riwayat_jabatan` (`id_riwayat_jabatan`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=211515 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When i run this query :

```
MariaDB[database_name]>  EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl_riwayat_jabatan
            WHERE id_riwayat_jabatan = 1234;
```

There result would be:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think the key is `NULL` because the "id_riwayat_jabatan" isn't at first order of indexes.

How can i rearrange the order the indexes ?
And additionally, Does the index make my given query above run faster ?

**UPDATE the table with its records sample**

[tbl_riwayat_jabatan.sql](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7osim8oe6l5g5xv/tbl_riwayat_jabatan.sql?dl=0)

Comment: You have a primary key and a key on id_riwayat_jabatan ,the key is superfluous. The order that the keys are defined in the create table does not define which key the optimiser will use and the optimiser may choose not to use any key if not using any key is the optimal execution plan.

Comment: *I think the key is NULL because the "id_riwayat_jabatan" isn't at first order of indexes.* Server explains why no index used. You use a constant which is not present in index - so output is empty, and no execution needed. Fill your table with the data, select by existing value - and the index will be used.

Comment: @Akina But if i change where condition to id_pegawai the key is exist with name id_pegawai. Actually i can still search by id_riwayat_jabatan with this query:
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl_riwayat_jabatan WHERE id_pegawai = 1234`.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am not sure. In that answer he said _"It basically means that one of your where criteria did not match any records"_ . In my case why the WHERE criteria didn't match any records ? While there is a record for that criteria.

Comment: You will also get this error if the table is empty.perhaps the query is not looking at the db you think it is- can you publish sample data please (As text int the question)

Comment: @P.Salmon i have include my table with some records into the question. But with .sql ext.

Comment: I have loaded the data provided and run the explain and get the same extras message , I have also run the select without the explain and no records are returned a visual examination of the data also shows there is no record where id_riwayat_jabatan = 1234 or where id_pegawai = 1234

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually the 1234 value is just a sample. i put another value when i tested the query.
I think i put `id_riwayat_jabatan = 2000` if i am not mistake.

Comment: have you tested with another value that has record ?

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl_riwayat_jabatan WHERE id_riwayat_jabatan = 129549; is the last record in your sample and both the explain and query work as expected.

Comment: Try testing on sqlfiddle.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am sorry for late replay. Yes you're right. Might be i didn't realize that the `id_riwayat_jabatan = 2000` was empty.
I have chacked `EXPLAIN SELECT` for another `id_riwayat_jabatan` with empty row give the same result as well ( key column is null).
Otherwise would result the key column is exist, in my case the key is PRIMARY.